# DBMS_XMLQuery and SELECT FOR UPDATE

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I have this PL/SQL code:

```
qrs := 'CURSOR cur IS SELECT * FROM ' || table|| 
         ' WHERE ' || direction || '=0 AND rownum <= 2000 FOR UPDATE';
v_ctx := DBMS_XMLQuery.newContext(qrs);
DBMS_XMLQuery.GetXML(v_ctx);
DBMS_XMLQuery.closeContext(v_ctx);
```

,and after I have got the XML I'd like update the selected rows:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE ' || table || 
        ' SET ' || direction || ' = 4 WHERE CURRENT OF ' || cur;
```

Could somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation of 11g R2 [suggests](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_xmlque.htm) using  [DBMS_XMLGEN](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_xmlgen.htm) instead.

```
create table so2in (id number, proc number, desc_ varchar2(20));

insert into so2in values(100, 0, 'desc of 100');
insert into so2in values(101, 0, 'desc of 101');
insert into so2in values(102, 0, 'desc of 102');
insert into so2in values(103, 0, 'desc of 103');
insert into so2in values(104, 0, 'desc of 104');

create table so2out(r1 clob, r2 xmltype);

declare
  qryctx dbms_xmlgen.ctxhandle;
  cur sys_refcursor;
  r1 clob;
  r2 xmltype;
begin
  open cur for
    select id, desc_ from so2in where proc = 0 and rownum <= 2 for update;

  qryctx := dbms_xmlgen.newcontext(cur);
  dbms_xmlgen.setrowtag(qryctx, 'Description');
  dbms_xmlgen.setrowsettag(qryctx, 'Descriptions');

  r1 := dbms_xmlgen.getxml(qryctx);

  update so2in set proc = 1 where proc = 0 and rownum <= 2;

  dbms_xmlgen.restartquery(qryctx);

  r2 := dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(qryCtx);

  update so2in set proc = 1 where proc = 0 and rownum <= 2;

  insert into so2out values(r1, r2);

  dbms_xmlgen.closecontext(qryctx);

  commit;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played with this XML stuff but

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE ' || table || 
        ' SET ' || direction || ' = 4 WHERE CURRENT OF ' || cur;
```

cur is the identifier of the cursor, not the contents of a local variable so it is more likely to work with

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE ' || table || 
        ' SET ' || direction || ' = 4 WHERE CURRENT OF cur';
```

That assumes the context of cur is retained, which I suspect it won't be. For a start, 'CURRENT' inmplies one row but you are selecting up to 2000. I think you will need to pick out the identifiers of the (up to) 2000 rows selected and update individually.

A wider description of the situation may help

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'd like select rows and generate an xml from them and after updated the direction column of those rows. I think I can't do this with DBMS_XMLQuery because I can't give the coursore to the UPDATE statement. I try to solve my problem some other way. Bye!